# How to manage views programmatically in an iPad storyboard application using Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have created an iPad storyboard application using the newest version of Monotouch. My first screen is a login screen that I only want to show if the user has not saved his credentials. If credentials are available I want to instead navigate to the UITabBarController that is the second scene. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this. I tried creating an instance of the UITabBarController and pushing to it but it does not work.

```
homeScreen = new HomeTabBarNavigator(this.Handle);
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(homeScreen,true);
```

HomeTabBarNavigator is a UITabBarController that is already linked to other scenes. I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set   to an instance of an object
```

I assume I am getting this error because I have not defined any views to the ViewControllers property of my HomeTabBarNavigator. I was hoping that those views were already defined but that does not seem to be the case. Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find is to call PerformSegue on the controller. Here is some example code:

```
this.PerformSegue("LoginSegue",this);
```

The controller that is loaded is the LoginController, and LoginSegue is a Segue that points to the HomeTabBarNavigator. While it is not perfect, the applications loaded the tabbar properly.

I used this [stackoverlflow iOS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047146/alternative-ways-to-push-view-controllers-with-storyboard-programmatically)  as the basis for my solution.