# Using uitextviewcontroller to go to another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uitableview

So want I want to be able to do is click on a button, have a tableViewController pop up appear and then click on one of the entries to bring me to a new view.

I already have the tableView pop up set up with the proper entries that I get from an NSArray.

I just don't know how to make it so that when I click on an entry, it brings me to my desired view. I believe it has something to do with the following default function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

but I'm not sure. I have an NSArray *array of entries and a MyViewController class and so if you can help me make it do something like the following it'd be great:

```
if(array entry 1) go to MyViewController1
if(array entry 2) go to MyViewController2 
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

get called when you click on the tableview.the `indexpath` in the method gives you the cell you selected

so the `indexpath.row` gives you the entry on the array which should be viewed.amke the logic upon that

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 int selectedEntry=indexpath.row;
 switch (selectedEntry) {
        case 1:
            //goto viewcontroller 1
            break;
        case 2:
            //goto viewcontroller 2
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Push methods

Using [storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047146/alternative-ways-to-push-view-controllers-with-storyboard-programmatically)

Comment: I see, thanks! But I'm still confused as to how I'd actually go about changing the view to the next view controller. Like how would I go about implementing the lines in the switch statement that you commented out?

Comment: From the sounds of it, it seems like he created his app without first embedding his root view controller into a UINavigationController, otherwise, for each of the switch statement, it'll be a simple [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];

Comment: How do I embed the root view controller?

Answer (score 0):

this is the thing you have to do mine friend:
when selecting a row this delegate method is called up.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

     switch (indexpath.row) {
            case 1:
                {
                ViewController1 *VC1=[ViewController1 alloc]init];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC1 animated:No];
                 break;
                }
           case 2:
               {
                ViewController2 *VC2=[ViewController2 alloc]init];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:No];
                break;
               }
          default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

hope this helps you mine friend..

Comment: So apparently this method would only work if I first embed my root view controller into a UINavigationController...but I don't quite know how to do that either. 

Is this something I also do in the UITableViewController?

Comment: You have to just use the reference  of UINavigationController instead of Self.navigationController mine friend

for Example: an reference UINavigationController *navi; 
then you have to use like this      

[navi pushViewController:VC2 animated:No];

Comment: So I declare and initialize a UINavigationController *navi in my .h file as a property and then initialize it as navi = [[UINavigationController alloc]init] in viewDidLoad() and then after that in didSelectRowAtIndexPath() I write 

ViewController1 *VC1=[ViewController1 alloc]init];
  [self.navi pushViewController:VC1 animated:No];


But this doesn't work either.

Comment: add a breakpoint into this delegate and first check is it working?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     int selectedEntry=indexpath.row;
     switch (selectedEntry) {
            case 1:
                ViewController1 *vc = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];    
                // Push View Controller 1 onto Navigation Stack
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
                break;
            case 2:
                ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];    
                // Push View Controller 2 onto Navigation Stack
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can also Present Modally like this:
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.row==1)
{
//Go to view
}
else if(indexPath.row==2)
{
//Go to view
}


}
```